# Why is my mat-menu display being overridden

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm really new to Angular and Material. For my course project I'm creating a menu drop and putting many buttons and nested menus on it. However, buttons are going in a row direction.

I thought putting the style to be flex and and column flex-direction would be enough, and that actually works on Inspect directly in the browser. HOWEVER, Angular is not only totally ignoring my `.scss` file, but is also ignoring the inline style changes.

SCSS

```
mat-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

HTML

```
<button class="material-icons mdc-top-app-bar__navigation-icon mdc-icon-button" mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menuSide" aria-label="Open navigation menu">menu</button>
...
<mat-menu #menuSide="matMenu" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
  <button mat-button>Materiales</button>
  <button mat-button>Centros</button>
  <button mat-button>Canjeos</button>
</mat-menu>
```

[image: Actual looks of the menu]

[image: styles]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are using it the wrong way: [angular material menu example](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/examples#menu-icons)

Your buttons code should look like

```
<button mat-menu-item>
  //...
</button>
```

Now concerning why your styles are "overriden", it is probably because:

1- Component styles (your app components) are encapsulated AND isolated.

For a global style, you should define it on the global level (styles.scss). Be careful not to stuff it just because it's convenient, you'll end up regretting it. You could still use ng-deep, but it's really a bad idea and it has been deprecated for a long time.

For material components, [you should use custom theming](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming)

2- Material is based on mdc tokens. If you inspect the generated code, you'll see that there are wrappers and many html tags + mdc classes used in order to render the right component with the right styles. In other words, it's exactly like when you include one of your components.

Comment: when I try to add mat-menu-item it just hides the menu button and prevents further interaction

Comment: Also, I tried to change colors and make a dark-theme with style.scss but it's just totally ignoring that file. even if I remove, add it or anything from angular.json it just defaults to the default theme and ignores the file.

Comment: You should edit your question, and add some details on what you are trying to achieve exactly concerning theses buttons

Comment: What I want to achieve is already in there. I want to get them to go as a column instead of as a row. When I try to use mat-menu-item the menu button (The one that summons the menu) loses it's icon and functionality. Thanks for the help tho, I will try and see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by following the advice of using mat-menu-item.

However, as long as is a button it won't work. I had to use divs and (click) to get it working as a button.